# javascript canvas rotate text without rotate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making rolling_board. (I attached my code, you may refer to this.)

It,s my problems :

1. I want to give degree to text without rotate function in canvas because rotate function is rotate whole canvas.
2. And I tried to turn the entire board but gave up because of the arrow that had to be fixed.

For this reason, I have to turn the board and the text except the arrows. I also want to solve this problem via canvas rather than html.

it's my code. It will only add, delete, and rotate. not name, color, percentage.

(Non-English language is Korean. If you see comment perhaps the result will be understandable without knowing the meaning.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>rolling_board</title>
    <style>
        *{margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing:border-box;color:#333;font-family: sans-serif;}
        li{list-style:none;} a{text-decoration: none;color:inherit;}
        .float:after{content:"";clear:both; display:table;}
        
        .wrap{width : 400px; margin: 0 auto;}
        
        .wrap-setting{width:100%;border:2px solid black;padding:10px;}
        
        .box-setting{width:100%;height:90%;padding:10px;}
        .btn-run{width:100%;height:40px;border:1px solid black; border-radius: 4px; background-color: #5a5a5a;color:white;cursor:pointer;}
        
        .list-setting{padding:10px;}
        .list-setting li{border-bottom:1px solid #363636;padding:4px;}
        .list-input-name{width:100px;}
        .list-input-num{width:40px;}
        .list-input-color{width:25px;}
        .btn-list-remove{width:20px;margin-left:7px; cursor:pointer;background: none;border:none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap float">
        <canvas id="can" class="left"></canvas>
        <form class="wrap-setting" id="form-setting" action="">
            <div class="box-setting">
                <div class="box-setting-setting">
                    <h3>setting</h3>
                    <button type="button" id="btn-list-add">add+</button>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-setting" id="list-setting"></ul>
            </div>
            <button id="run" class="btn-run" type="submit">rotate!</button>
        </form>
   </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var c = document.getElementById("can");
        var can = c.getContext("2d");
        
        //attribute of circle board
        var circle = new Array();

        //size of board
        var board_size  = 400;
        
        var quantity = 0;
        var ai = 0;
        
        var status = "true";
        
        //draw arc
        function arc(start,size,fill){
            can.fillStyle = fill;
            can.beginPath();
            can.arc(0,0,board_size/2-10,start*Math.PI*0.02,(start+size)*Math.PI*0.02);
            can.lineTo(0,0);
            can.fill();
            can.closePath();
            
            //arrow
            can.beginPath();
            can.moveTo(-5,0-board_size/2);
            can.lineTo(0,20-board_size/2);
            can.lineTo(5,0-board_size/2);
            can.fillStyle = "#434343";
            can.fill();
            can.closePath();
            
            can.fillText("hello, world!",20,20);
        }
        
        //set board
        function board_set(stac){
            can.clearRect(0,0,board_size,board_size);
            for(var i=0; i<circle.length;i++){
                arc(stac,circle[i].size,circle[i].color);
                stac += circle[i].size;
            }
        }
        
        //rotate borad
        function board_rotate(){
            if(status == "false") return false;
            status = "false";
            var stac = 0;
            var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8000-4000)+4000)/1000;
            var a = setInterval(function(){
                board_set(stac);
                stac+=n;
                n-=0.015;
                if(n<0){
                    clearInterval(a);
                    board_set(stac);
                    status = "true";
                }
            },10);
            return false;
        }
        
        //add list
        function list_add(){
            quantity++;
            
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            
            var name  = document.createElement("input");
            var num   = document.createElement("input");
            var color = document.createElement("input");
            
            name.className   = "list-input-name";
            num.className    = "list-input-num";
            color.className  = "list-input-color";
            
            name.placeholder = "list"+(ai+1);
            num.type         = "number";
            color.type       = "color";
            
//            name.required    = "true";
//            num.required     = "true";
//            color.required   = "true";
            
            num.max = "99";
            num.min = "1";
            
            /* random color */
            var red   = Math.floor(Math.random()*255).toString(16);
            var green = Math.floor(Math.random()*255).toString(16);
            var blue  = Math.floor(Math.random()*255).toString(16);
            red =   red.length   == 1 ? red   = "0"+red   : red; 
            green = green.length == 1 ? green = "0"+green : green; 
            blue =  blue.length  == 1 ? blue  = "0"+blue  : blue; 
            var rgb = "#"+red+green+blue;
            color.value = rgb;
            
            /* set name input */
            var name_wrap = document.createElement("span");
            var name_text = document.createTextNode("이름 : ");
            name_wrap.appendChild(name_text);
            name_wrap.appendChild(name);
            name.onchange = function(){
                console.log("color changed");
            }
            
            /* set percentage input */
            var num_wrap = document.createElement("span");
            var num_text = document.createTextNode(" 확률 : ");
            num_wrap.appendChild(num_text);
            num_wrap.appendChild(num);
            
            /* set name color */
            var color_wrap = document.createElement("span");
            var color_text = document.createTextNode(" 색 : ");
            color_wrap.appendChild(color_text);
            color_wrap.appendChild(color);
            
            /* set remove button */
            var remove = document.createElement("button");
            var remove_text = document.createTextNode("X");
            remove.className = "btn-list-remove";
            remove.id = "btn-list-remove";
            remove.type = "button";
            remove.appendChild(remove_text);
            remove.onclick = function(){
                if(quantity == 2) return;
                var id = parseInt(li.getAttribute("data-index"));
                for(var i = 0 ; i<circle.length; i++){
                    if(circle[i].index == id){
                        var size = circle[i].size;
                        circle.splice(i,1);
                        for(var j=0; j<circle.length;j++){
                            circle[j].size += size/circle.length;
                        }
                    }  
                }
                li.remove();
                quantity--;
                board_set(0);
            }
            
            li.appendChild(name_wrap);
            li.appendChild(num_wrap);
            li.appendChild(color_wrap);
            li.appendChild(remove);
            
            ai++;
            li.setAttribute("data-index",ai);
            
            document.getElementById("list-setting").appendChild(li);
            circle[quantity-1] = {size:20,color:rgb,index : ai};
            circle_standard();
            board_set(0);
        }
        
        function circle_standard(){
            for(var i=0; i<circle.length; i++){
                circle[i].size = 100/quantity
            }
        }
        
        document.getElementById("form-setting").onsubmit = board_rotate;
        
        window.onload = function(){
            c.width  = board_size;
            c.height = board_size;
            can.font = "20px Arial";
            can.translate(board_size/2,board_size/2);
            board_set(0); list_add(); list_add();
            document.getElementById("btn-list-add").onclick = list_add;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You use rotate but save and restore the transform so that you can draw other stuff without the transform. . Eg `ctx.save() ;ctx.rotate(angle); /* draw rotated stuff */ ctx.restore(); /* draw unrotated stuff*/`

Comment: @Blindman67  
oh, i got it. I will try this, and let you know.

Comment: @Blindman67 it's working, thanks :)